# Where can I find more information about the stream-specification

Tags: javascript, stream, specifications

I want to read up about the browser stream api (not node!)

I know there is the stream specs here: https://streams.spec.whatwg.org/

But lots of methods are never described in words, like, what they actually DO e.g.

```
3.12.4.3. respondWithNewView(view)

    If ! IsReadableStreamBYOBRequest(this) is false, throw a TypeError exception.
    If this.[[associatedReadableByteStreamController]] is undefined, throw a TypeError exception.
    If Type(view) is not Object, throw a TypeError exception.
    If view does not have a [[ViewedArrayBuffer]] internal slot, throw a TypeError exception.
    If ! IsDetachedBuffer(view.[[ViewedArrayBuffer]]) is true, throw a TypeError exception.
    Return ? ReadableByteStreamControllerRespondWithNewView(this.[[associatedReadableByteStreamController]], view).
```

Its just listed what is thrown under which conditions and what is returned.
Is there any other ressource where these things are described in a more human friendly way?

Comment: Check this https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html.

Comment: @croraf I am talking about the browser stream api not nodes stream implementation. Will edit to reflect that

Comment: OK. I see the edit now. Isn't this the same API, but different implementation?

Comment: No unfortunately not. Completely different stuff. I was astound myself